# Selecting one of multiple overlapping features (in same feature class) based on attributes

Tags: arcgis-pro, overlapping-features

I have a feature class containing thousands of overlapping buffer features representing service coverage. Each buffer has an attribute of service quality (numeric, high is good). I want to determine the lowest number of buffers needed to cover my extent, and currently there are a lot of overlapping buffers that can be reduced and still cover the same area (see picture). Is there a way to select from overlapping polygons in the same feature class based on which ones have a higher attribute value for the service field?

I am currently using ArcGIS Pro and am able to use python, QGIS, and Microsoft SQL Server.

[image: Overlapping buffers with varying service values]